# Android - Zoomed View translation limiting

Tags: java, android, graphics

I have a simple Custom View and Scale Gesture detector implemented for the Pinch (zoom) gesture, just like this (found it on StackOverflow too):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;

public class MyImageView extends View {

private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;

    private Drawable mImage;
    private float mPosX;
    private float mPosY;

    private float mLastTouchX;
    private float mLastTouchY;
    private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;

    public MyImageView(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    mImage=act.getResources().getDrawable(context.getResources().getIdentifier("imag­ename", "drawable", "packagename"));

        mImage.setBounds(0, 0, mImage.getIntrinsicWidth(), mImage.getIntrinsicHeight());
    }

    public MyImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public MyImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // Let the ScaleGestureDetector inspect all events.
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

        final int action = ev.getAction();
        switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            final float x = ev.getX();
            final float y = ev.getY();

            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;
            mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
            final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
            final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);

            // Only move if the ScaleGestureDetector isn't processing a gesture.
            if (!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
                final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

                mPosX += dx;
                mPosY += dy;

                invalidate();
            }

            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;

            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
            final int pointerIndex = (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) 
                    >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
            final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
            if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
                // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
                final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
                mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
                mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
            }
            break;
        }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.save();
        Log.d("DEBUG", "X: "+mPosX+" Y: "+mPosY);
        canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
        mImage.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

            // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 10.0f));

            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Then, when the View is Zoomed, I want to limit the Translation to go only to the boundaries of the Image that is being drawn in onDraw(). 
I thought I'll have that controled with Canvas.getClipBounds() just to see what's the zoomed image offset off of the Viewport, but then I cannot figure out how to control that.

To be more precise, I want my View not to translate the Image more than the 0 Left and 0 Top points of the View.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
```

To

```
 if((mPosX<0)&&(mImage.getIntrinsicWidth()<canvas.getWidth()))
      mPosX = 0;
 if((mPosY<0)&&(mImage.getIntrinsicHeight()<canvas.getHeight()))
      mPosY = 0;
 canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
```

Comment: mPosX when the View is Zoomed is 0. So it changes its value only after translation (if I move it to right it gets positive, if I move it to left it gets negative) ...

Comment: Exactly! Dont you want it to stay positive ? Seems I still didnt get the question fully ): .. please explain

Comment: No, if there is offset to the right, I want also to translate to the right too. So I want to translate the image as long as there are parts of it that are supposed to be seen. Something like mimicking ScrollView but without a ScrollView :) So I ZoomIn - there is offset to the left, and to the right too, and I want to translate to the left so that I can see the hidden part from the right and I want to translate to the right so that I see the hidden parts from the left.. hope I am clear :/

Comment: I wish I could understand exactly what you mean ):

Comment: I mean: I need to move/translate the image until it gets to its corners. (x, y) or (width, height) .. that's all.

Comment: can you try this .. I think I wont be able to help because I have not worked before with Canvas but try this