# Is it possible to draw 2 Rect and excerpt the first?

Tags: android, draw, rect

EDIT: --> HEY GUYS! <--

i am working on an "Image based App"!
What i want to do is:

1. Take a photo (done)
2. preview the Photo with an Overlay!
3. Crop the Photo

So the problem is the Overlay! I have an SurfaceView with the taken Photo inside and now i want to see a square like a window (rect2) and around an alpha overlay (rect1 some kind of black with alpha 50%). 
Is it possible to draw 2 Rect, one in full size (rect1) and one in a smaller size (rect2) and then cut the smaller out of the first Rect??

```
______________
|Rect1       |
|   ______   |
|  |Rect2 |  |
|  |      |  |
|  |______|  |
|____________|
```

I am using Android 2.1. I know in 2.3.3 there is an BitmapRegionDecoder! this thing does almost what i want to do. 
At the moment i draw 4 Rect and leave a smal hole in the middle for the window but it is like an pain in my A** to move this sqare and resizing it.

EDIT: What i want to do is like in Facebook, if you upload a picture as Profileimage you have to move and resize a square on your image for the "avatar"-image on the left when you post something...

So i hope everything is clear and you can help me!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a FrameLayout, like container, and for positioning your SurfaceView (your rect).
And with a removeView you can delete the rect you want, by capturing with a findviewbyid.

I hope this help you. bye

Answer (score 0):

```
public class yourActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new yourCanvas(this));
}

class yourCanvas extends View {
    public Panel(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Bitmap yourBitmap = getYourBitmap();
        canvas.drawBitmap(_yourBitmap, 50, 50, null);
        canvas.drawRect(0,0,canvas.getWidth(),50,null); //top rect
        canvas.drawRect(0,0,50,canvas.getHeight(),null); //left rect
        canvas.drawRect(50+yourBitmap.getWidth(),0,canvas.getWidth(),canvas.getHeight(),null); //right rect
        canvas.drawRect(0,50+yourBitmap.getHeight(),canvas.getWidth(),canvas.getHeight(),null); //Bottom rect
    }
}
```

}

---

*previous answer* suitable if you just want to create a border for your imageview

I would like to propose the following:

1. setting an [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html)'s bitmap to your bitmap
2. setting the background color to the color you want the outer rect to be
3. setting the padding parameters to get the desired dimensions

Comment: Okay that sounds good but there is a reason for the SurfaceView and the Image as Bitmap inside! I get the Image out of the sdcard and scale it to the width and height of the SurfaceView. After setting the square i know all informations to crop the original image!

Comment: Maybe its not clear ennough (sorry for my english) With the smal square i want to choose a part of the Image. You can move the square arround and scale it, but you always the the hole image in the background. By clicking ok the image will cropped/cutted like the square!

Comment: the same like you take a picture for Facebook as profilepicture, than you have to move a square arround to crop the picture for your thumbnail image in Facebook...

Comment: oh I see ... ! that is completely different .. the image is the background .. I see

Comment: this it what i already did! I also have a Line around the inner border. The Problem is to move it arround and scale it by multitouch. When i move, i have to move it slow to reache the border. I also can scale it by multitouch. But i thought there is a easier way to do this: like: draw one Rect in bordercolor and subtract a second (my little window). Isnt it possible? Like a mask or something, because it makes it more easier to move and scale

Comment: ok I was answering someone who did these ... let me search for his question and show you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910719/android-zoomed-view-translation-limiting/6910939#6910939